# Kubernetes LoadBalancer doesn't work properly

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod

I made simple Java web app (secure.war) with Tomcat (tomcat:9.0-alpine) and I expected that ***requests will be balanced among pods*** in Kubernetes. I even set maxKeepAliveRequests="1" in Tomcat connector (server.xml) to turn off Keep-Alive features. I use Minikube to run it locally.
My configs:

*deployment.yaml*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tomcat
          image: optionix/mywebapp:5.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

*service.yaml*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: v-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Then I run:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl port-forward services/v-service 8080:8080
```

Now you can make requests on `http://localhost:8080/secure/getId` and you will see UUID which was generated at application startup.

**Actual behaviour**: you always see the same UUID (it means that only one pod receive requests)

**Expected behaviour**: you see two different UUID one by one randomly (which means that requests balancing among two pods)

Comment: `kubectl port-forward` always connects to a single specific pod, even if it uses a Service to find it.  Services always load-balance between their Pods regardless of type; you only need a LoadBalancer service if you want your cloud provider to automatically create an externally visible load balancer for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze if I understood your right: instead of port-forwarding service, I need expose my service to make it visible externally?

Comment: Correct, or have a proxy pod inside the cluster that forwards to the Service.

Comment: @DavidMaze I found another approach: `minikube service my-service-name` and its open default browser with my service where all balancing is working! Thank you a lot for hint!